# How to fix Blue Screen appearing after GameObject is removed in Unity 2d Project

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have been successfully building and running a Unity 2D game, but started receiving a Blue Screen during one of my operations. Specifically, when I close a popup and remove all of its child Game Objects, the entire Game Screen turns dark blue (the default background color of the main camera). The music for the game still plays and clicks are still registered if you click in the right area (I can still press the back button, just can't see it).

If I remove 1 gameobject, this problem doesn't come up. But once I have to remove 2 game objects, the entire screen turns blue.

This is my function for removing my game object in case it helps, which works perfectly when it comes to actually removing the gameObjects correctly (game objects to be removed are created from prefabs). I think the problem may be with the camera for some reason, but I have no clue as to why it happens on this function.

```
public void Remove(int index)
        {
            float toggleWidth = toggle.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x;
            DestroyImmediate(scrollSnap.pagination.transform.GetChild(scrollSnap.NumberOfPanels - 1).gameObject);
            scrollSnap.Remove(index);
            scrollSnap.pagination.transform.position += new Vector3(toggleWidth / 2f, 0, 0);
        }
```

I don't receive any errors or warnings in the console. Just a blue screen once more than one GameObject is removed

**EDIT:**

Turns out my main Canvas's *planeDistance* was being changed from 100 to 3200. I still have no clue as to why this change occurred...but for anyone else having a similar issue with a dark blue screen appearing in the middle or start of their game, then please check the values your canvas and camera in the Inspector. Simply controlling the planeDistance did the trick for me!

Comment: This is likely something to do with the camera, I assume you're using an orthographic camera for a 2D game. Run the game and put unity into 3D mode and have a look at where the camera is in relation to your objects

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'm new to Unity and didn't think of that as a solution. I noticed that the plane distance of the canvas changes drastically, but I'm still unsure of why it changes from the code above. Looking into that now

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by putting game in 3d mode and realized that the camera is positioned very far from the sprites, just change the z-axis and again go to 2d mode.

Answer (score 1):

Made a new scene next to the sample scene when i started my sprite learning game. Forgot all about that.
When I had to publish it, In the Build Settings, I had the wrong scene selected. So It published an empty scene  instead of my game.

Comment: it is better to add this sort of "I found a mistake" text to the original question. If you do find an actual answer to your question then do answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Move your camera in Z-axis position**, it could be too far from object or it is behind the object, you can also check it by 3D mode the check the object position and change it in positive and negative values.